# Download a image from server to android and show in imageview

Tags: java, android

I have an server (i use GlassFish). I am able to send Json or XML etc. with http to my android device. I saw an example to upload a picture from my android device to the server. That converts my picked image to byte, converts to String and back at my server. So i can put it on my PC (server). 
Now i just want the opposite: get a picture from my PC and with the URL get the image (bitmap here) to imageview. but with debugging bmp seems to be "null". google says its because my image is not a valid bitmap (so maybe something is wrong at my server encoding?).
What does i need to change to this code to get it working?

Server code:

```
public class getImage{
    String imageDataString = null;

    @GET
    @Path("imageid/{id}")
    public String findImageById(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        //todo: schrijf een query voor het juiste pad te krijgen!
        System.out.println("in findImageById");
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\vulst\\Desktop\\MatchIDImages\\Results\\R\\Tensile_Hole_2177N.tif_r.bmp");

        try{
            // Reading a Image file from file system
            FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            imageInFile.read(imageData);

            // Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
            imageDataString = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageData);
            imageInFile.close();

            System.out.println("Image Successfully Manipulated!");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
        }
        return imageDataString;

    }

}
```

and this is the android side (android studio):

```
public class XMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            java.net.URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String line) {
        super.onPostExecute(line);
        byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decode(line , Base64.DEFAULT);

        try {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length);
            ivFoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("tag" , e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we need your log!

Comment: Use https://github.com/square/picasso . Picasso is easy to use.

Comment: I don't see the point to return the image encoded. Why don't you just return the url so at the Android part, you can load it?

Comment: thanks for all you answers it was really helpfull!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `HttpURlConnection`?

Here's a sample code:

```
private class SendHttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/image.jpg");
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.connect();
                    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    return myBitmap;
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.d(TAG,e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(ID OF YOUR IMAGE VIEW);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
    }
```

I hope i could help

Comment: this is indeed working, but i had this one already. thanks for the answer

Comment: glad to help mate :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Glide it is simplest way to load image
This is how you can save image

```
Glide.with(context)
                        .load(image)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                                String name = new Date().toString() + ".jpg";

                                imageName = imageName + name.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResourceReady: imageName = " + imageName);
                                ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(mContext);
                                File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                File myPath = new File(directory, imageName);


                                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                                try {
                                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
                                    resource.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } finally {
                                    try {
                                        fileOutputStream.close();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

and this is how you can read the image

```
ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(mContext);
    File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String path = directory.getAbsolutePath();
    path = path + "/" + imageName;
    Glide.with(mContext).load(path).into(your imageview);
```

Comment: sorry but i don't understand. I can repeat my question: i want to show a picture from my PC on my app without using drawable..? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Or can you give me a clear video to do this using Glide?

Comment: Thank you, Shashank, for this one line [name.replaceAll("\\s+", "")] which saved my hair.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)?

For `build.gradle` in your app module:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
Glide  
    .with(context) // replace with 'this' if it's in activity
    .load("http://www.google.com/.../image.gif")
    .into(R.id.imageView);
```

Comment: Yes indeed, i already used this for a previous thing, but i used Picasso. but how can i make such a link like in your example:  .load("http://www.google.com/.../image.gif") Because the file comes from my PC

Comment: @lambotje, You can't link your Android device with PC, because both are in different operating system. Put the image into your sdcard, and then it will work.

Comment: thanks, i know what you are saying, but i have the path to each picture in my database so what i will at the end is: get the link to the path, and send that picture to my android device. So normally the OS has nothing to see with this? hope you can help!

Comment: Use localhost server which will send the asset( here the picture) to android on request. Request with the path from database.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Base64.encodeBase64String(imageData)` with out using the `URLSafeString`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i can try this: imageDataString = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageData); But what you are saying does not exist in the Netbeans library: maybe there is the fault? i use this import: import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

Comment: Sorry I updated the answer it needs to be `encodeBase64String`. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

If there are people who are also trying to do it my way, this is working:

```
public class XMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            java.net.URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String line) {
        super.onPostExecute(line);
        byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decode(line , Base64.DEFAULT);
        try {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length);
            ivFoto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("tag" , e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
@Stateless
@Path("getImage")
public class getImage {

    //todo: capture error inandroid +  take just path!
    String imageDataString = null;

    @GET
    @Path("imageid/{id}")
    public String findImageById(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        //todo: schrijf een query voor het juiste pad te krijgen!
        System.out.println("in findImageById");
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\vulst\\Desktop\\MatchIDImages\\Results\\R\\Tensile_Hole_2177N.tif_r.bmp");

        try{
            // Reading a Image file from file system
            FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            imageInFile.read(imageData);

            // Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
            imageDataString = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageData);
            imageInFile.close();

            System.out.println("Image Successfully Manipulated!");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Image not found" + e);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
        }
        return imageDataString;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code is useful.

go to your MainActivity.java and try this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;

public void downloadImage(View view)
{

    Log.i("Button","Tapped");

    DownloadImage task = new DownloadImage();
    Bitmap result = null;
    try {
        result = task.execute("https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/0/0a/ElsaPose.png/revision/latest?cb=20170221004839").get();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);

}

public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... imageurls) {


        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;

        try {
            url = new URL(imageurls[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            InputStream in =httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return myBitmap;

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }



    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}
```

}

Don't forget to add this piece of code in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```