# Upload image to web server from Android

Tags: php, database

I am developing an Android application that allows user to upload images from their Android to the a 000webhost server, by referring to [this link](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-upload-image-to-php-server/), I had managed to successfully send the image to the web server (file manager?).

However, I'd like to send the image to the database of the server instead, but I had been facing issue inserting the image into the database, below is the PHP code I am using:

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$con = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);

if (mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo 'Error: Connection failed.';
    exit();
}

// Get image string posted from Android App
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];

// Get file name posted from Android App
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];

// Decode Image
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

$sql = "INSERT INTO images (bitmap, name) VALUES ('$binary', '$filename')"; 
//mysqli_query($con, $sql)

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'Success';
} else {
  //  Images will be saved under 'upload' folder
    $file = fopen('upload/'.$filename, 'wb');

//  Create File
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**My database named images has 3 columns:**

```
id INT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
bitmap TEXT
name VARCHAR(100)
```

I tried passing just the filename into the database earlier and it worked, so I am suspecting the data type for bitmap is wrong.

Or should I, instead of passing the image into the database, keep the path of the image in the web server instead?

EDIT: 
I got rid of the if else statement and only saved the filename into the database, the image is saved to the server. For retrieval, I defined the path to the folder where images are being kept at, and used readfile() to send the image back to Android, using HTTPUrlConnection from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557167/download-a-image-from-server-to-android-and-show-in-imageview).

Comment: Use this in android MultipartUploadRequest ... if you need code of MultipartUploadRequest I can provide

Comment: The image was successfully sent from Android, so I think the problem lies on the server-side

Comment: try `addslashes(base64_decode($base))`. if not working check why the query insertion is failing.

Comment: @new_user, I tried using addslashes(), the image can be inserted into the database but the image can not be rendered in the file manager, and in the database the bitmap is shown in funny characters (question marks and squares).

Comment: that is actually a expected behaviour. you will be able to see the picture in the file-manager only if the insertion fails according to your code.

I suggest you to save the file in filesystem and store the path in the database.

Comment: I saved the file in filesystem and the filename to the database (since the path is the same for every images) according to your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the files in server and keep the filename in DB is the preferred solution. Also there is upload limit for every server. You can increase by editing server configuration or using php ini_set.